# squid proxy and parental control: list of unwanted sites

Tags: squid, parental-controls

I have a web proxy with squid installed, that realize a 
parental control function.

At the moment i have to put manually all the sites that i want
to block.

There is a site/institution that publish a public list of sites,
suitable to use in a parental control function?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a website [URLBlacklist](http://urlblacklist.com/), that can help you with this.  This list works best if you use SquidGuard or Dansguardian with your squid proxy server.  I am using Dansguardian and it works like a dream.  You can also look at [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/), they have a webfilter that works really good. This will also work with your squid proxy.

Comment: +1 to OpenDNS - I use this for my Nephew's computer.

Comment: Wow! These are two great solutions! Thanks a lot!